# Can't see variable inside the function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component where I put some data inside a variable `users` to read it in another function. When I print this variable inside constructor and print it on my console I can see it, but when I do the same inside another function I got undefined. I already tried to declare it as private and public and get the same result.

How can I declare this variable to see it inside another method?

this is my component:

```
import { tap, take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

export class SharedProofsComponent implements OnInit {

  page = 1;
  pageSize = 4;
  collectionSize = COUNTRIES.length;
  countries: User[];

  users: User[];

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {

    this.firestore.collection<User>('users').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
    // console.log(this.users);
    this.refreshCountries();
    });

  }

  refreshCountries() {
    console.log("USERS:");
    console.log(this.users); // here I got undefined

    this.countries = this.items
      .map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))
      .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

EDIT:

If I put a static constant on my function I can get the data:

```
this.countries = COUNTRIES
  .map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))
  .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
```

But if I do this:

```
   this.countries = this.items
  .map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))
  .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
```

I got the error:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User[]>'.
> .map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))

Comment: If you put it inside    this.refreshCountries(); the subscribe, it will show.  Remember there is a delay in getting data, so, you cannot do it immediately

Comment: I edit my question, could you see it again, please?

Answer (score 3):

You call method before getting data and besides you fetch users asynchronously. When you call `refreshCountries` no any data in `users` variable.

Should work

```
this.firestore.collection<User>('users').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users; // get users
    this.refreshCountries(); // call method
});
```

Comment: I edit my question, could you see it again, please?

Comment: Where do you declare `items`?

Answer (score 3):

Add `this.refreshCountries();` inside the subscribe callback, so that. it becomes:

```js
this.firestore.collection<User('users').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(users => {
  this.users = users;
  this.refreshCountries()
});
```

Comment: I edit my question, could you see it again, please?

Comment: What error are you facing exacty? Like `users` is undefined or `'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User[]>'` or both?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful because when you are fetching the data with the subscribe in firestore in the constructor method it is a async call. If you are using the refreshCountries function before the request is resolved, you cannot see the result properly.

Comment: I edit my question, could you see it again, please?